# How do I make takeLatest consider url, params, and method?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I'm using Saga's `takeLatest` to abort all requests except the latest. This works fine, but now I want to only abort requests which *don't* have identical url, params, and method.

I know Saga uses the `type` attribute to compare actions (just like vanilla Redux does), but I've also added `url`, `params`, and `method` to my actions because I was hoping there there was some way to do something like

```
yield takeLatestIf((action, latestAction) => {
    const sameType = action.type === latestAction.type;
    const sameUrl = action.url === latestAction.type;
    const sameParams = areEqual(action.params, lastAction.params);
    const sameMethod = action.method === lastAction.method;

    return sameType && sameUrl && sameParams && sameMethod;
});
```

which should only abort requests if all 4 of those attribute comparisons are false.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right from your question, you want this:

1. Like standard `takeLatest()`.
2. But when a duplicate request is made, ignore it and wait for the one already executing (a reasonable use case).

So I took `takeLatest()` implementation [provided in the docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takelatestpattern-saga-args) and adapted it to your scenario:

```js
const takeLatestDeduped = (patternOrChannel, compareActions, saga, ...args) => fork(function*() {
  let lastTask
  let lastAction
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(patternOrChannel)
    // New logic: ignore duplicate request
    if (lastTask && lastTask.isRunning() && !compareActions(lastAction, action)) {
      continue
    }
    if (lastTask) {
      yield cancel(lastTask)
    }
    lastTask = yield fork(saga, ...args.concat(action))
    // New logic: save last action
    lastAction = action
  }
})
```

We have three cases:

1. No running task: start the new one - *standard behavior*
2. Running task, got non-duplicate: cancel old one, start new one - *standard behavior*
3. Running task, got duplicate: ignore - *new custom hehavior*

So I added case #3 logic:

1. Ignoring duplicate request (nothing should be done in this case, so I `continue` to handling next action).
2. Saving last action for future duplicate check.

Comment: takeLatest aborts all actions except the *latest*. The latest request should never be aborted even if it's a duplicate...only *earlier* duplicates should be aborted. Is there a way to modify your function to maintain this convention?

Comment: So you need a takeLatest, but for duplicates it shouldn’t cancel the last task, but run two duplicate tasks concurrently instead? It’s possible, but could you explain your use case a bit? I’ll try to implement it today.

Comment: It should cancel *all* duplicate actions *except* the latest action. The issue is what constitutes a "duplicate" action. Only actions that have the same type, url, params, method should be considered a duplicate action. The use case is a standard REST request to an api for data that returns different data depending on the url parameters.